# Bash Shebang for dummies?

Tags: bash, shell, script

I have some bash scripts I have setup that mostly use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

but I regularly come across some that look like

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#!/bin/bash -x
#!/bin/bash -ex
```

and so on.

Can someone explain the meaning and benefits of these shebang options and whether they apply to other shebangs?

Comment: Those options are specific to Bash (or other interpreter). They may be the same for other shells (dash and ksh, for example), but they would be different for other interpreters such as AWK and Python. You can use many of the options that the interpreter accepts. The options are interpreter-specific while the shebang is a kernel feature.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If a script `/path/to/foo` begins with `#!/bin/bash`, then executing `/path/to/foo arg1 arg2` is equivalent to executing `/bin/bash /path/too/foo arg1 arg2`. If the shebang line is `#!/bin/bash -ex`, it is equivalent to executing `/bin/bash -ex /path/too/foo arg1 arg2`. This feature is managed by the kernel.

Note that you can portably have only one argument on the shebang line: some unices (such as Linux) only accept one argument, so that `#!/bin/bash -e -x` would lead to bash receiving the single five-character argument `-e -x` (a syntax error) rather than two arguments `-e` and `-x`.

For the Bourne shell `sh` and derived shells such as POSIX sh, bash, ksh, and zsh:

- `-e` means that if any command fails (which it indicates by returning a nonzero status), the script will terminate immediately.
- `-x` causes the shell to print an execution trace.

Other programs may understand these options but with different meanings.

Answer (score 24):

They are options passed to `bash` see `help set` for more info, in this case:

```
-x  Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.
-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

Comment: +1  And `-ex` does both

Comment: It's confusing because they look like command-line options passed into Bash.

Comment: @Caoilte: And indeed they are (from [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)): `In addition to the single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command, bash interprets the following options when it is invoked: [...]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to mention an even better – as in more portable – alternative:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

The example above uses `env` to find the `bash` executable, which isn't always at `/bin/bash`. Ye olde `#!/bin/bash` scripts don't work on [NixOS](https://nixos.org/), for example.

If you use `env` as demonstrated above, you can't supply an argument such as `-e` to `bash` (as far as I know). But you can do this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
```

Comment: I do this all the time, but I wouldn't say it's “more portable” — in fact, the risk of having the user run something completely different (from what you can assume a system ships with) is much greater. For example, Ubuntu still ships Bash 4, while a user may choose to run Bash 5.

Comment: Yea the `env` usage is not good especially for scripts that run python because you simply do not know if the default `python` is version 2 or 3 and that makes a world of difference for scripts that need a specific version. Better to be explicit than crafty

Comment: Requiring `$PATH` to be set by the user is a recipe for trouble. For a script that's part of a package, it's preferable for for the package maintainer to set the `#!` to suit the class of system that it will be installed onto, or failing that, for it to be detected during installation. Otherwise it's preferable for the administrator to set the `#!` line when installing the script so that their users don't need to know or care. Of course, if the instructions originally just said “Run `bash scriptname`" instead of "Run `./scriptname`" that would also solve the problem.

Comment: @smac89 If it matters then you can use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` Though that doesn't help if you need something from python 3.6 (eg string interpolation), and the user has python 3.2 and 3.8. Isn't versioning wonderful?

Answer (score 1):

Starting a script with `#! /path/to/bash -option`, or equivalently running
`bash -option /path/to/script`, has the same effect as inserting `set -option` inside the script just after its `#!` line.

`set -x` is essentially just for debugging; you wouldn't want it left on normally.

The effect of `set -e` is a lot more complicated than the manual suggests. The more precise description is roughly:

> After invoking `set -e`, if an *untested* command exits with a non-zero status, it will cause the shell to exit with that exit status.

I say *more precise* because it's still pretty vague: the list of situations where the command is considered *tested* is arcane and difficult to predict. The exact rules differ between shells and even change between versions of the same shell.

`set -e` does *not* cause Bash to exit in response to non-zero exit status of any commands:

- between `if`/`elif` and `then`; or
- between `while`/`until` and `do`; or
- following `!`; or
- followed by `||` or `&&` or `&` (though for `&` the corresponding `wait` or `fg` may fail); or
- followed by `|`, unless `set -o pipefail` is in effect; or
- inside `$( ... )` when used as part of a command (not bare assignments and/or redirections, which means that `foo=$( bar )` will fail if `bar` fails, but `local foo=$( bar )` will not); or
- within a compound command where the above apply; or
- inside a shell function invoked from anywhere the above apply.

The effects on compound commands and shell functions are recursive.

Because the shell itself exits with a non-zero status, the effect can propagate out of a subshell.

The `!` exemption applies even if the inverted exit status is ignored.

Conversely, `set -e` triggers on *every other* non-zero status, regardless of whether it means "fail" or simply "false". For example `((x++))` will have a non-zero "fail" exit status when `x` is initially 0.

Because it's such a mess, there's a school of thought that says `set -e` should be avoided in favour of explicitly checking all commands.

Or if you still want to use `set -e`, remember to write `!` in front of any `((arithmetic))` groups.