# Why variables in shell are not inherited by sub-shell now that the sub-shell is implemented by fork?

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

When running shell command in shell scripts, a sub shell process is generated. Doesn't the process is generated by `fork function`? Why the variables that are not exported are not inherited? In `fork`, all context of parent process should be copied to sub process.

Comment: Could you explain the scenario that you're concerned about more specifically?

Comment: If I enter `a=x; sh -c "echo $a"` I find that `x` is correctly displayed. What are you doing that's different?

Comment: @AFH But when `a=x` define a variable, open a sub shell using `sh` and `echo $a`, the value of a is not inherited. I wanna know why? Doesn't the sub shell is generated by `fork()`?

Comment: `a` was not previously defined, so `a=x` _did_ define a variable, and a local one at that, and as I proved the value was inherited. I don't know whether `fork()` or `vfork()` is used to create the sub-shell, but whichever is used it appears to work as I would expect. What are you doing to make you think it isn't inherited?

Comment: @AFH The OP is right, local variables don't get inherited. Your example should be `a=x; sh -c 'echo $a'` if you want to test inheritance.

Comment: @user3872279 Which shell is the question about ? bash / sh ?

Comment: @lemonsqueeze - You're absolutely right: silly me! When I tried it with single quotes it showed that local variables are indeed not inherited, but `export a=x; sh -c 'echo $a'` shows that exported variables **are** inherited. They are added to the environment and can be picked up by any process scheduled by the shell. I have tried this with both `sh` and `bash`, as well as running a program which lists its environment variables (a four-line C program with `while (*envp) puts(*(envp++));` as its central loop).

Comment: This now brings us back to the original question: why would `fork()` not allow local variables to be inherited? I _think_ the answer is that the variables are inherited by the child process immediately after the `fork()`; however, `fork()` is almost always followed by an `exec...()` function, which creates new local variables, but maintains the parent's environment.

Comment: Looks like we're getting somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

The first error here is in thinking that the shell just runs `fork()` to execute an external command and that the description of `fork()` is thus a description of the operation of the shell.  In reality both the parent and the child process do a whole lot of additional stuff.  And in particular the child calls `execve()` to run the external command.

At this point, from reading the manual page for `execve()` a light should be dawning.  One of the parameters to the system call is *the environment that the overlaid process image will have* at program startup.  Obviously, there's no magic under-the-covers environment passing by the operating system.  The shell has to explicitly concoct an environment and pass it to `execvce()` in the child process.  That environment can be whatever the shell likes.

Which brings us to the second error.  Environment variables are not shell variables.  When the shell program starts up, it *imports* environment variables into shell variables of the same names (and in one shell, into shell functions).  When it comes to spawning an external command, it then *exports* the shell variables into the (new) environment that it creates and passes to the kernel in `execve()`.  In between whiles, all that you do in scripts and interactively with *shell variables* affects those variables, which are distinct from the shell process' environment.  (The shell process' environment generally remains largely untouched and unused after import at program startup.)

Which — Hey presto! — explains why the `export` shell built-in is called "export".

And which also explains how built-ins such as `set` see unexported variables.  They don't involve overlaying the shell program with another program, and don't involve setting up a new environment to pass to `execve()`.  Similarly, creating subshells with parentheses doesn't — by itself — involve `execve()` and so doesn't involve exporting shell variables to create an environment.